# Query DynamoDB Data with EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, elastic-map-reduce

I am looking for a way to query the AWS DynamoDB data with SQL Syntax using amazon EMR.

I have my DynamoDB table set up and ready. How can I import/query the data using Hue? The table in DynamoDB has a size of around 8GB.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below steps:-

**Hive to query non-live DynamoDB data:-**

1) Export Data from DynamoDB to Hive

Refer Section : Exporting Data from DynamoDB in EMR Hive Commands link below

2) Use Amazon EMR to query data stored in DynamoDB

Refer Section : Querying Data in DynamoDB in EMR Hive Commands link below

3) Use Hue to run the queries (i.e. run Hive queries from Hue workbench)

[EMR Hive Commands](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/EMR_Hive_Commands.html)

[Hue Supported](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-hue.html)

**Hive to query live DynamoDB:-**

1) Create Hive table to map to DynamoDB table

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/EMR_Interactive_Hive.html

2) Once you create the Hive table and run queries on it, it will refer the live DynamoDB table to get the data

**Disadvantage :** It consumes DynamoDB read or write units for each execution. In other words, it will cost you for each query execution.

**Sample code:-**

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE hivetable1 (col1 string, col2 bigint, col3 array<string>)
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.dynamodb.DynamoDBStorageHandler' 
TBLPROPERTIES ("dynamodb.table.name" = "dynamodbtable1", 
"dynamodb.column.mapping" = "col1:name,col2:year,col3:holidays");
```